# Line spacing at specific parts of the document

Tags: setspace

I use `setspace` package for line spacing in the document. I want 1.5 line spacing in the text and bibliography, I want the default line spacing in the table of content between the equations.

Because I use `setpacked`, line spacing does not affect the content of tables and caption of the figures and tables, this is good for me.

I use sperate file for chapters.

`.cls` file

```
\LoadClass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=8mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,font=it]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\BiblatexHungarianWarningOff
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
```

.txt file

```
\documentclass[]{main}
        
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document}
....
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]